# difference between Java atomic integer and C# Interlocked.Increment method

Tags: c#, java, multithreading, thread-safety

Im just wondering, is there a difference between how you increment a static variable in Java and C# in an threaded enviroment?

In Java you use atomic int:s to make this operation and in C# you use Interlocked.Incement(ref yourVar)

I by this dont mean the code you write but how it is actually locks the memory and does the actual increment.

Comment: This is not a language question. Different versions or different implementations, or different platform targets of a virtual machine can affect the internal behavior of such functions.

Comment: Actually java is VERY, very much CAS based (in its very core) and it offers CAS alike primitives too. So the impl: either LL/CS or natural CAS doesn't really matter. C# uses WinAPI interlocked function to impl. which if memory serves well it's add w/ LOCK prefix.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interlocked operation doest not lock memory, it rather emits LOCK prefix to the instruction depending on the operation. That cause processor to assert bus lock so only instruction is executed once.
You can further look at the [following article](http://lists.canonical.org/pipermail/kragen-tol/1999-August/000457.html)

Since the link is no longer working here is the archived version
https://web.archive.org/web/20140325112655/http://lists.canonical.org/pipermail/kragen-tol/1999-August/000457.html

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 2):

In the case of Java - the "how it works" depends on the instruction set of the execution platform.  I was reading (earlier today while waiting for an interminable OS upgrade to finish) that on x86 AtomicXxx classes are implemented using a Compare and Swap (CAS) instruction.

Comment: Yes, atomic stuff is loop( if (cas) break ) in java.  Interlocked in C# can be impl via LOCK ADD.